# Lenovo Y500 camera not working

Tags: webcam, lenovo

I am new to Ubuntu and linux in general. I was able to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Lenovo Y500 after many tries, everything seems to work perfectly except the builtin camera. I've installed "cheese" and I get the following error everytime I start it up:

> - (cheese:2353): WARNING **: Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video0'

I've tried it also on Skype, but still its not working. The built-in camera brand is "Bison, Chicony, Liteon"

Is there any chance that I can make it function? Any help is highly appreciated, I dont want to keep windows 8 just to use skype :(

Comment: it works fine on my ideapad Y500.. hey, does your system has issues hibernating or suspending???

Comment: @newjagger I have no issues with hibernation and suspension, it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 it the camera is working fine.