# Lenovo IdeaPad Y500 Builtin Webcam does not work in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webcam, lenovo, ideapad

I bought a Lenevo IdeaPad Y500.
I erase its windows and install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on it.
I can not use my webcam on my laptop. I check Skype and guvcview non of them can detect my webcam.
The following link said it will be working by upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04.
[Lenovo Y500 camera not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293013/lenovo-y500-camera-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the most up to date kernel.

Try opening up Terminal and entering the following command, entering your password as necessary.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will update your software and kernel hopefully getting the software you need for the camera.

Comment: I did the update but no change. this is the error that I get from guvcview.
no codec detected for H264
no codec detected for MP3 - (lavc)
Checking video mode 640x480@32bpp : OK 
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Input/output error
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Input/output error
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Input/output error
VIDIOC_STREAMON - Unable to start capture: Input/output error

Also there is no change in skype.

Comment: As mentioned in Ubuntu Forum by decreasing the resolution the guvcview come to the work. so what should I do now for my skype.